# Is it possible to remove a github account

Tags: git, github

I created an account on github.com.

Now i want to delete it.

I want to create another account.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Probably one of the worst questions I've ever seen on stack overflow....

Comment: @guru This sort of question belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ +1 because I don't think it's a bad question, but off-topic, don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to your [account admin page](https://github.com/account/admin).
2. Click the angry red button:
   [image: angry read button]

Answer (score 3):

Go here: https://github.com/account/admin

and delete your account.